# Using switchMap to dispatch an action fails while map works

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

I just started using  **ngrx** and **ngrx/effects**.

In the following code using `switchMap` to get the results from `concatLatestFrom` and dispatching an action fails while using `map` works.
Why is that??

Using `switchMap` doesn't compile at all and when i hover on it, it shows

> Argument of type '([action, staff]: [{ per_page: number; } & TypedAction<"[Admin] Fetch All Staff From Store">, Staff[]]) => ({ per_page: number; } & TypedAction<"[Admin] Get All Staff Start">) | { ...; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: [{ per_page: number; } & TypedAction<"[Admin] Fetch All Staff From Store">, Staff[]], index: number) => ObservableInput'.
> Type '({ per_page: number; } & TypedAction<"[Admin] Get All Staff Start">) | { type: string; }' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput'.
> Type '{ per_page: number; } & TypedAction<"[Admin] Get All Staff Start">' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput'.
> Property '[Symbol.iterator]' is missing in type '{ per_page: number; } & TypedAction<"[Admin] Get All Staff Start">' but required in type 'Iterable'.ts(2345)

which i dont understand.

This Gives an error.

```
GetAllStaffFromStore = createEffect(() =>
    this.action$.pipe(
      ofType(adminActions.FetchAllStaffFromStore),
      concatLatestFrom((action) =>
        this.store.select(fromAdminReducer.selectStaff)
      ),
      switchMap(([action, staff]) => {
        if (staff.length === 0) {
          return adminActions.GetAllStaffStart({ per_page: action.per_page });
        } else {
          return {
            type: "Getting Staff From Store",
          };
        }
      })
    )
  );
```

This works

```
GetAllStaffFromStore = createEffect(() =>
    this.action$.pipe(
      ofType(adminActions.FetchAllStaffFromStore),
      concatLatestFrom((action) =>
        this.store.select(fromAdminReducer.selectStaff)
      ),
      map(([action, staff]) => {
        if (staff.length === 0) {
          return adminActions.GetAllStaffStart({ per_page: action.per_page });
        } else {
          return {
            type: "Getting Staff From Store",
          };
        }
      })
    )
  );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`switchMap` has to return a new `Observable`

Wrapping the response in `of` operator should help.

```js
import { of } from 'rxjs';

GetAllStaffFromStore = createEffect(() =>
    this.action$.pipe(
      ofType(adminActions.FetchAllStaffFromStore),
      concatLatestFrom((action) =>
        this.store.select(fromAdminReducer.selectStaff)
      ),
      switchMap(([action, staff]) => {
        if (staff.length === 0) {
          return of(adminActions.GetAllStaffStart({ per_page: action.per_page }));
        } else {
          return of({
            type: "Getting Staff From Store",
          });
        }
      })
    )
  );
```